# Render multiple templates in one layout iron:router

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, iron-router

I've been staring at this for an hour now and re-typed it as many ways as made sense but the problem is I am only seeing the "social" template on the /sites/ routing.

On the meteor client side I am running this code (using iron:router)

```
    Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
    });

    Router.route('/', function () {
      this.render('welcome', {to:"main"});
    });

    Router.route('/sites/', function () {    
      this.render('social', {to:"main"});
      this.render('websiteaddform', {to:"top"});
    });
```

On the HTML side, here is the layout template:

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
    <header>
        {{>yield top}}
    </header>
  {{>yield main}}
</template>
```

there definitely aren't any obvious errors ie. typos in the templates,any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `{{>yield "top"}}` instead of `{{>yield top}}`

Answer (score 0):

This stays the same:    (in router.js in Lib folder for both client and server)

```
    Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
  });

  Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('welcome', {to:"main"});
  });

  Router.route('/sites/', function () {
    this.render('social', {to:"main"});
    this.render('websiteaddform', {to:"top"});
  });
```

And here you forgot the "quotes"   (in applicationlayout.html folder /client)

```
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
    <header>
        {{>yield "top"}}
    </header>
  {{>yield "main"}}
</template>
```

And for making it complete I added a sample template:  (the file templates.html in folder /client/templates)

```
<template name="welcome">
  welcome
</template>
<template name="social">
  social
</template>

<Template name="websiteaddform">
  websiteaddform
</Template>
```